# Unit testing the parametrized test programmatically with out Suite

Tags: java, unit-testing

I do have some parametrized test and i want to run the tests **programmatically** and not with `annotation processors` e.g `@Suite` `@RunWith(Suite.class)`  , is there a way that i can access and invoke the test classes from other test classes ?

- Some test cases

```html
@SpringBootTest
class Test {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"first", "second"})
    public void example(String values) {
    ...
    }
    
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EngineTestKit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.platform.testkit/org/junit/platform/testkit/engine/EngineTestKit.html) that provides support for executing a test plan for a given TestEngine and then accessing the results via a fluent API to verify the expected results.

```
EngineTestKit
            .engine("junit-jupiter")
            .selectors(selectClass(Test.class))
            .execute().testEvents().assertStatistics(o -> o.failed(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run test classes from code like that.

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
junit.run(Test.class);
```

You can read more about that here: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-tests-run-programmatically-from-java